Why is it saying inappropriate ioctl for device for USBDEVFS_DISCONNECT?
I'm trying to write a program in assembly that cuts power/disconnects connection to a usb device of my choosing, I was told that USBDEVFS_DISCONNECT would do it, but when I execute the program, it gives me this error.

ioctl(3, USBDEVFS_DISCONNECT, 0xffffffe7) = -1 ENOTTY (Inappropriate ioctl for device)

Here is my source code
%include "../x8664/fileio.s"
global _start

section .text
_start:
        openat -100, file, UGO_RW, STDIN
        jmp Mmap

Mmap:
        mov r8d, eax
        mov eax, 0x9
        mov edi, 0x0
        mov esi, 0x1000
        mov edx, 0x1
        mov r10d, r8d
        syscall


IoctlDisconnect:
        mov edi, r8d
        mov edx, eax
        mov eax, 0x10
        mov rsi, 0x00005516
        syscall
        jmp IoctlDisconnect

exit:
        mov eax, 0x3c
        xor edi, edi
        syscall

section .data
file:
        db "/dev/bus/usb/001/004", 0

And this is the macro that I'm using
;read/write
STDIN equ 0
STDOUT equ 1
STDERR equ 2

;chmod
O_READ equ 0o004
O_WRITE equ 0o002
O_EXEC equ 0o001
G_READ equ 0o040
G_WRITE equ 0o020
G_EXEC equ 0o010
U_READ equ 0o400
U_WRITE equ 0o200
U_CREAT equ 0o100
O_RW equ 0o006
O_RX equ 0o005
O_WX equ 0o003
O_RWX equ 0o007
G_RW equ 0o060
G_RX equ 0o050
G_WX equ 0o030
G_RWX equ 0o070
U_RW equ 0o600
U_RX equ 0o500
U_WX equ 0o300
U_RWX equ 0o700
UGO_RWX equ 0o777
UGO_RW equ 0o666
UGO_RX equ 0o555
UGO_WX equ 0o333

;openat
;CWD equ -100

;lseek

%macro read 3
    mov eax, 0x0
    mov edi, %1
    mov esi, %2
    mov edx, %3
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro write 3
    mov eax, 0x1
    mov edi, %1
    mov esi, %2
    mov edx, %3
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro chmod 2
    mov eax, 0x5a
    mov edi, %1
    mov esi, %2
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro fchmod 2
    mov eax, 0x5b
    mov edi, %1
    mov esi, %2
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro open 3
    mov eax, 0x2
    mov edi, %1
    mov esi, %2
    mov edx, %3
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro openat 4
    mov eax, 0x101
    mov edi, %1
    mov esi, %2
    mov edx, %3
    mov r10d, %4
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro syncfs 1
    mov eax, 0x12d
    mov edi, %1
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro close 1
    mov eax, 0x3
    mov edi, %1
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro lseek 3
    mov eax, 0x8
    mov edi, %1 ;File Descriptor
    mov esi, %2 ;Offset in bytes
    mov dx, %3  ;Seek Mode
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro fsync 1
    mov eax, 0x4a
    mov edi, %1
    syscall
%endmacro

%macro fstat 2
    mov eax, 0x5
    mov edi, %1 ;fd
    mov esi, %2 ;buffer
    syscall
%endmacro

